# multilevel dropdown with javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, nested

I am trying to create a dynamic multilevel dropdown with the following format:

```
<li><a href="catID">CatName A</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="CatNameA">
    <li><a href="subcatID">subCatName AA</a></li>
    <li><a href="subcatID">subCatName AB</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>(iterated with diff values about a dozen times.)
```

My code:

```
$.each(data.cat, function (i, item) {
console.log(item.catID + " " + item.catName);
$("#divCategory").append('<li id='+item.catName+'><a href=/Category/GetCategory?_cat=' + item.catID + '>' + item.catName + '</a>');
    if(item.subCat.length > 0)
    {
        $("#"+item.catName).append('<ul class="dropdown-menu">');
            $.each(item.subCat, function (j, itemsub) {
                console.log(itemsub.SubCatID + " " + itemsub.SubCatName);
                $("#" + item.catName).append('<li><a href=/Category/GetSubcategory?_subcat=' + itemsub.SubCatID + '>' + itemsub.SubCatName + '</a></li>');
            })
            $("#" + item.catName + "li:last").append('</ul></li>');
    } else {
        $("#divCategory").append('</li>');
    }
})
```

With the code above, when I check it seems that this line is not working properly:

```
$("#" + item.catName + "li:last").append('</ul></li>');
```

When I check the generated HTML:

```
    <li><a href="catID">CatName A</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu"> </ul>  --> the closing UL is at the wrong spot.
    <li><a href="subcatID">subCatName AA</a></li>
    <li><a href="subcatID">subCatName AB</a></li>
</li>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: something you need to change your code like this... http://jsfiddle.net/48J5v/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you creating an element, use also end tag like this:

`$("#"+item.catName).append('<ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul>');`

Then, you do not need to append end tags later, new child elements will be place *into* created element.

Anyway, your selector is probaly wrong, because it should be:

```
$("#" + item.catName).append('</ul></li>');
```

But anyway you should not do it in this way.